# Is it possible to start a PhD in mathematics at the age of 29?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, oa.operator-algebras, career

I graduated with a bachelor’s degree in mathematics. I was initially focused on branches in     analysis like operator algebra. At the third year of my undergraduate study, I experienced a financial loss in my family. It was only a slight loss and would not influence the life and regular plans of my family. But at that time I was not mentally strong enough and I could not concentrate on study. I postponed two years to graduate, in 2020.

These days I am trying to apply for a master program in mathematics. My GPA is not top, but fair enough, and I also did my graduation thesis carefully. I applied for several programs in Europe and received the conditional admission of Uni of Göttingen, but my Toefl grade did not meet the requirements. This year I have prepared all the things and I am going to apply for several master’s programs in Germany.

I am currently interested in low-dimensional topology and want to select this area as my direction. But when I apply for a PhD, I am 29 years old, is it a huge disadvantage? I also referred to several persons working on geometric topology, and the time cost seems to be high. But I am still enthusiastic about mathematics and want to get a bread.

Anyone could give me some suggestions?

Comment: As far as I know it is not uncommon to start a PhD later in life, and 29 is not even that late. Age alone should not be much of a disadvantage.

Comment: You may want to look at this thread. The "age gap" is somewhat smaller there but you should find some stories shared there encouraging! https://mathoverflow.net/q/59999/30186

Comment: This post is also tangentially related: [Too old for advanced mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/7120) And maybe you can find some related posts also on [academia.se].

Comment: Would [this topology workshop](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~dmargalit7/tsw22/index.shtml) by Ian Agol help?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible start a math PhD at 29, 39, 49, 59, or any age really. Nobody cares if you are 25 or 29, but they might care about the "age" of your degrees (I.e. if it has been many years since you received your MSc degree). I think there is a preference for fresh graduates. But from what you write this should not be an issue if you get into a MSc program in Germany and do well there.

Comment: @spin Thanks for your encouragement.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237002/too-old-to-start-math/237007#237007 ... dispute being closed, it has many good answers.

Comment: Two things, there:

First, of course it's possible to start a PhD in mathematics, or any other subject at age 29 or if you really want to, at age 99. Is that much not obvious?

What grants or loans you might qualify for is a different Question altogether…

Comment: If someone answered 'no', would you believe them?

Comment: @LamarLatrell If you're referring to "Does this answer your question?" that is auto-generated by the StackExchange software when someone votes to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I started my PhD in mathematics at 35, and had 15 years of academic career after that. Now working in industry as a mathematician. So, yeah, it is very possible.

Comment: @Bruce Which field did you select at first?

Comment: @TimothyChow I was asking the original querent to consider a possible answer to their titlular question.

Comment: @Alex I was personally interested in symmetry groups of formal expressions, but after developing some of the ideas the specific context became computation within matrix semi groups. I was thinking that this would have applications in computing, but that line was never really pursued and after graduation I did a lot of computational geometry - using experience from the work on the geometric structure of said semi groups. The crucial thing is to find a good postdoc position as soon as you graduate.

Comment: [Lefschetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Lefschetz) started his PhD at age 33. So no age is too late.

Comment: 29 is the median starting age for a phd. This is a silly question.

Comment: @Brady, source?

Comment: @GerryMyerson First google result for 'median starting age for phd'. https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/sites/8389c70e-en/index.html?itemId=/content/component/8389c70e-en#:~:text=Other%20findings,doctoral%20graduates%20are%20international%20students.

Comment: @Brady, OK, but the question is whether it's possible to start a PhD **in math** at age 29. What's true for, say, sociology doesn't necessarily hold for Mathematics.

Comment: Not a subject matter expert, I do not have a phd. But OECD average starting age is 60% of new admittence is between ages 26 and 37.

Comment: @Morten, is that average specifically for math PhDs? or is it an average over all academic disciplines? (Also, starting a PhD isn't the same as completing one.)

Comment: A peer of mine started his PhD in math (focus on CS ML) at US Ivy League in his 50s after "retiring" from his career in finance, is still working on it 6 years later... enjoys taking his time. To have done a PhD without the added stress of personal finances and time pressure... wow.

Comment: @GerryMyerson
1: It is the starting age. He is asking if he is told "old" to start one, he isn't. 
2: Starting one, and completing one, isn't the same sure.... 
But his ability to complete the course, is unrelated to the question itself, is he to old to start. 
The answer is no. The question is, why do you want one? (His motivation for getting it is way more relevant as to if he will be able to complete it, but that really isn't his question)
It is just a broad average of all phd's across the board for all OECD countries.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You can always make up additional qualifiers for why a data point doesn't apply to a particular special situation. What about the starting age in a specific country? For a specific subfield? For a person with specific family history? I do not see any reason to require this level of specificity for a simple data point like the starting age of a degree program.

Answer (score 35):

I don't think being 29 could ever be considered a disavantage on the intellectual or creative level to start a PhD. The comments below your question give you links to lists of famous mathematicians who were late starters. One famous example is Stephan Banach who wrote the equivalent of his master thesis at 28 and got the equivalent of what we call today a PhD at age 30.

I would nevertheless advise to be very careful on other aspects of a mathematician's carreer. Unfortunately, such a career is rarely based solely on talent and genius, unless you solve the equivalent of the Riemann hypothesis in your field. Financial and sociological issues are very important and might become more and more difficult to tolerate as you grow older.

If you plan to get a PhD and then move to industry and/or work for private companies, I guess (though I don't have a formal proof, only examples from friends and colleagues) that your professional life won't be any significantly different or harder than that of your colleagues who got their PhD a few years earlier than you. On the other hand, you have to know that there is an extremely fierce competition for jobs in academia.

It has now become standard to be on very unstable positions (called post-doc positions) for at least 3–4 years after the completion of your PhD. And sometimes up to 10 years! (I have seen that among younger colleagues.) During these years, you need to gain recognition from the bigwigs in your field, so that they can support your application for the next stage of your career: the tenure track position (which I will describe below). And that might be extremely difficult, even if you prove some big results.

I know someone who, as a PhD student, answered an *implicit* \footnote{added as per suggested by Dan Petersen} question of Serre <s>(you might call it a *conjecture*)</s> on cohomological invariants of some finite groups. Instead of congratulating him for his results, Serre became mad at this guy, accused him of stealing his ideas, saying that *"the main steps of the proof were already known to him, and that he was going to publish very soon a paper answering his own question."* The guy was forced by Serre's affiliates to rewrite his paper and explicitly mention that his work contains no original contribution as *"everything was already known to Serre"* (but of course not published).

His career in abstact algebra, which should have certainly flourished in the best possible way, considering his brilliant debut, brutally stopped there. This guy was only 25 or 26 at the time, and was strong enough to start a new career in another field. I can't however imagine him doing the same if he was 36 (instead of 26).

But that is a single example, and obviously, most PhD don't end up like this. On the other hand, even if you succeed in having your peers acknowledge your work in a positive way and find some good post-doc positions, you still are in the middle of the jungle. Indeed, if you gain enough support from the bigwigs in your field, you can only upgrade from post-doc positions to a tenure track position.

While tenure track positions are certainly less insecure than post-doc positions, they still aren't permanent positions. They last between 5 to 10 years, and the same game has to be played again with the bigwigs: publish (a lot and frequently) on the subjects which **they** consider to be interesting, gain their recognition and ask them to support your application.

Then, finally, after 10 to 15 years of such a life (where you might have to move out places every 2 or 3 years), you may hope for a stable and permanent position. Which means that if you start your PhD at 29 and plan to work in the academia, you might secure a permanent position at 40 at the earliest. Granting the fact that you have been able to give plain satisfaction to the numerous bigwigs you will encounter during this 10 to 15 years period of time.

I do believe this is really an important issue to consider before getting bogged down in the academia. You really don't feel the same about those things whether you are in your late twenties or you come close to 40.

Comment: Surely post-doc and tenure-track is a great challenge,but I really want to realize my dream from young. I often regret if I could become more calm when I was a undergraduate, I will not face the trouble now.

Comment: @Alex : I am certainly not tryng to discourage you from fulffilling your dreams. Mathematics is certainly worth devoting ones life to it. I am just trying to warn you that academia is far from being what it looks from this outside. It is a jungle! In my opinion, age only play a central role in some situations. When you are (very) young, you don't really care about job security and you recover very quickly from the humiliations the bigwigs may suject you to. I do believe that you become less and less able to tolerate such things when you get older.

Comment: And job security becomes more and more inportant when you grow older, especially if you plan to raise a family.

Comment: Which field are you working in currently?

Comment: For those curious, this seems to be the paper referred  to: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.6283.pdf . I do not understand why people like Serre do not understand that forcing (explicitly or implicitly) someone to write that makes you look like an enormous jerk.

Comment: @yser2520938: For what it's worth, the use of "eventually" in the sentence "*Eventually, we thank him for pointing out to us a mistake in
an earlier version of this paper*" is a bit unfortunate, because this seems to suggest that instead of thanking him at a sooner and more appropriate time, the author is only "eventually" now getting around to thanking him. Better would have been "We also thank him for ..." or "Additionally, we thank him for ..."

Comment: Regarding taking a PhD to industry: Be aware of the opportunity cost. Years invested in earning a PhD are years not spent building connections and industry-specific skillsets. (This is not to say a PhD-->industry is not worthwhile, but rather to be cognizant of the tradeoff.)

Comment: I think the anecdote about Serre in this answer is inappropriate for many reasons:
1) It is a disparaging accusation against a person identified by his real name, made by an anonymous user.
2) It is based only on second-hand information about an incident which happened 10 years ago.
3) The student is easily identifiable from your description (see the comment of @user2520938), who would perhaps not like the affair to be dragged out in public, either.
4) It is not relevant to the question of whether it is a good idea to start a PhD at age 29.

Comment: Finally, although I haven't met Serre, the description of how things happened sounds very unlike everything I have heard about him.

Comment: @DanPetersen : Life is full of unlikely events, sometimes very disappointing. I am sorry if this event involving Serre may shed some shadows on the naive picture of him you may have created for yourself. But the story happened exactly as I tell it. I was almost in first lines when it occured.

Comment: Furthermore it has very much to do with the question of the OP. Obviously not all PhD end up like this, but this is far more frequent than one could imagine. In my opinion, you can't jump into a PhD program without knowing that this possibility exists. Many Msc's students believe that doing a brillant PhD will grant them a nice career (at least for the beginning) and that is simply not always true. You have to be aware of that when you start a PhD  especially if you are a "late-stater"

Comment: @Libli Why don't you send me an e-mail about it and we can continue this discussion.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134523/room-for-libli-and-dan-petersen

Comment: Also, keep in mind that starting a tenure-track job later in life means, in many cases, starting with a very low salary that will not climb quickly. I think this answer, despite the controversy surrounding the Serre issue, is wise to heed. I think a *lot* of what is said about older mathematicians can be attributed not to mathematics, but to the surrounding issues of life that impede mathematics.

Comment: This answer is the kind of pure truth that is spoken so rarely in academia, but that almost every student/postdoc needs to know.

Answer (score 29):

I completed my PhD at the age of 32 which is not uncommon to Israelis. We often lose several years due to military service. So starting at 29 might be a bit late, but it is not a disaster. It is more about talent and commitment. Good luck.

Comment: Starting later in life, after having some life experiences can be a huge advantage.  I witnessed many Israeli students doing their Ph.D thesis at Cornell, after completing their IDF time.   They cut through their Ph.D work like a hot knife through butter.   People going to grad school, straight out of the high school -> undergrad degree cycle, often get dizzy from the array of discussion and research topics, math's tangled history.

Answer (score 21):

This is/was certainly possible.

*Proof* : Reuben Hersh started a PhD after 30 (born in 1927, he defended his thesis in 1962 at the age of 35) after having been working a decade as a machinist. He eventually became a successful professor at the University of New Mexico. His scientific work ranges from hyperbolic PDEs to Probability and Philosophy.

Comment: Hersh’s experience 60 years ago shouldn’t count for much here. At the time, American academia was expanding, the academic job market was plentiful, and PhDs were quicker. That’s no longer true in the US, and I doubt it’s true in Germany.

Comment: @MattF. The OP did not address the question of job market, but only that of feasibility of a PhD at the age of 29. Hersh's example shows that the answer is positive.

Comment: Check out Hersh's published dissertation, esp. p. 321: https://www.jstor.org/stable/24900768. Do you think someone today could get a PhD with a dissertation that "is virtually identical to" a paper only 18 pages long and described as "nothing but a straightforward use of Laplace and Fourier transformations"? I doubt it -- and that matters for someone today.

Comment: @MattF. Half (?) of the PhD theses in maths are either not cited, or forgotten after five years. That of R. Hersh is still a fundamental step in the theory of hyperbolic Initial Boundary Value Problem. Today, an advisor would ask the student (say R. Hersh grandchild) to elaborate around the 18 pages fundamental paper. It would extend to 100 pages, but the core of the thesis would remain about the same.

Comment: Maybe the math would be no better! But adding another 80 pages would add another 6 months or year to the PhD.

Answer (score 4):

Just another example: I graduated late, then worked 2 years outside university, then started my PhD, defended my thesis at 37, and at 47 I became associate professor. Since you ask this frequently: my field is dynamical systems.

BUT

It wasn't easy to catch up.
I had to accept a few things which look cool in your 20s but uncomfortable in your 40s.

Comment: Do your parents support this career? Is it not easy to overcome some anxiety of peer pressure in this process?

Comment: I was lucky enough to work in very good and supportive teams. The difficult part was to move every 2 years or less and to wait my mid 40s to start building my own family.

Answer (score 3):

As a yes or no question, then certainly yes.

You are at a tiny disadvantage though, which you obviously know to be posing the question.  And tiny disadvantages sometimes gradually get bigger, but sometimes they feeble into non-importance.  Ultimately, it probably won't be the deciding factor.  But it will manifest itself: on the professional level, it might mean you get judged negatively by some (short-sighted, and hopefully not many) professors/panel members; and on the personal level, it might mean you'll attach more importance to your family and financial status than you would have done a few years ago.  No one knows how it will play out, but those will be the issues.  That's all it is.

I don't know much but I can assure you that no one will be walking about thinking "omg they're just starting their phd".  But you're right that (referring to one of your comments) it isn't that easy to overcome the social/peer pressure, but what should be easy anyway.  Just make sure you're aware of it and have your approach to cope with it (and not just ignore it - I've seen too many people fail their Ph.D.'s not because they're mathematically incapable but because they don't know how to deal with the pressures involved).  Anyway, pretty soon you'll talk to enough people to realise few people care about your age, they just care what maths you do.

Also, as a small personal supporting note cause no one likes getting rejected and it was that bit that made me catch your post: good that you avoided Goettingen, my supervisor there literally told me I was too old to go for a postdoc (at 28).  So look at it as a bullet dodged, if it helps.  (By the way, Mihailescu is at Goettingen and he didn't start his Ph.D. until he was aroud 40!  (He's great by the way, incase this last paragraph is otherwise too negative.))

Comment: 28 is common even if this is only the first post-doc…what I have realized is that being admitted to a master program is not difficult, it is a challenge whether I can find a supervisor afterwards.

Comment: it will be more difficult, but not terribly so (at all).  there are plenty of posts here, on stackexchange, or on quora, about how to correctly approach a professor - learn about their research and if you find it interesting then tell them.  you can't really fake this.  and at that point they won't care about your age.  (usually, but ye unfortunately there will be some cases where "at a tie" you could get marked down.)  

it's good to acknowledge that you're starting older, but that's where it ends - don't let it worry you.  after that just focus on your mathematics.

Comment: Given what you say, why do you describe the disadvantage as tiny? Having less family time and less money are not tiny things for someone who has the values you suggest.

Comment: i agree, i think i was just trying to say that the gap *starts* smaller and either gets bigger (if you miss out on things because you're judged too old, but you would have been fine and it would have been a chance to "catch up", or because as you say your family means you have less time for maths so your output decreases but that of your "competitors" doesn't) or gets neutralised early on (either through luck or being particularly good or particularly hard-working).  but at the "beginning" there might not actually be that much difference between the candidates.

Comment: @tomos Thanks for your suggestions. Are you familiar with pure mathematics in Germany? I mean if there are comparatively abundant positions of phd there…

Comment: -ish familiar maybe.  but then again not really cause i don't know how it is in other countries.  but anyway, i think the best thing you can do is focus on your maths and not worry about the age thing - though you are right in acknowledging it so that you can deal with whatever anxieties you may have as a result (basing this on one of your comments somewhere here).  but ultimately there really are enough profs who will take on a candidate who's serious, regardless of age - this is certainly my overriding opinion.

Comment: i see many master's students not approaching potential supervisors correctly.  in my opinion, the fact that you start later really is a disadvantage, but a small one compared with all the other variables that are way more important (your maths, your networking, etc.)

Comment: @tomos Are you currently a post-doc on analytic number theory?

Comment: yep.  but all of what i wrote above is based on my phd experience

Comment: @tomos All the stories about those encouraging mathematicians are not uncommon because the rhythm of living and academics is quite slow in the 20th century. I am certainly more realistic compared to the period when I started my undergraduate study. What I plan to do is just to push myself and not to select too hard problems at the beginning…

Comment: well whatever happens, good luck:)

Answer (score 2):

I started my PhD at age 30, and don't feel my age was a significant obstacle. However, I believe almost no one should do a PhD, regardless of age.

Comment: how come? if i may ask

Comment: There's nothing about an academic career that makes it worth staying extra years in school, taking one or more temporary positions, having little control over the city one lives in, just in the (possibly unlikely) hope that one will eventually find a tenure track position. Not to mention the fact that anyone capable of doing a PhD in a technical field could likely get a job in industry making 2x or 3x as much as a professor.

Comment: @tomos What he said is not comparatively unrealistic, if one has not set up a family or other burdens…No doubt pure maths requires strong brain muscle, and people are definitely the strongest in their young 20s, I acknowledge that…Different persons also have different stamina, and certain physical exercise could help maintain better.

Answer (score 1):

May be I live in another part of the world? I never asked this question to myself when I started my PhD from Mathematics Department and I was 29 at that time :)

I thought I was too young to do a PhD :D

Comment: Which field are you working in?

Answer (score 1):

I think the bottom line is that some things are easier if you start earlier, but that talent and quality will ultimately find a way and that these things are not determined by your physical age.  If you have something original to say, you should still be able to say it regardless of your age.

Note that obtaining a PhD at a relatively old age is quite common for Israeli mathematicians and physicists.  For example, if you need inspiration, Yuval Ne'eman started his PhD in physics aged 33.  His main contribution (age 36) was his discovery of the classification of hadrons using $SU(3)$ flavour symmetry (known colloquially as the ''eightfold way'').  This is a major achievement in twentieth-century physics.

Comment: It's worth noting that Ne'eman's achievement was over sixty years ago: he was born in 1925, with the eight-fold way in 1961, and his related dissertation in 1962 (https://www.proquest.com/docview/1812968444).

Comment: You are right.  However, this does not contradict the fact that it is an interesting example of someone who started doing formal research relatively late in life but still made great advances.