# Industry jobs involving mathematics, machine learning and biology

Tags: soft-question, career, mathjobs, bioinformatics

I have a MSc in Mathematics and a PhD in Bioinformatics (in two different European countries); during the PhD I was developing computational methods to analyse DNA sequence data, mainly using a machine learning approach. 
I am currently doing a post-doc involving basic DNA sequence analysis and a bit of mathematical modeling, but I am seriously considering the idea of leaving academia.

I am browsing the internet looking for positions combining preferably mathematics and biology, but I cannot find any... could you please give me some indications of what types of jobs could match my skills?

I am trying to avoid working as a bioinformatician, because I have the feeling that involves too much grunt work, and it is more related to IT than math.

Comment: Good question, but wrong forum to ask it I think...

Comment: Can you recommend me a more appropriate forum?

Comment: Maybe academia.SE or the stats SE sites might be better, though really, I don't know if there is a good "career guide" forum that I could recommend.

Answer (score 7):

If you've done machine learning and worked with large data sets then many places will be interested in hiring you. For example, the NSA often hires mathematicians with these skills. So does Google. Also Microsoft Research, IBM, Hewlett-Packard, etc. I wrote a longer answer on several of these places [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88219/changing-careers-becoming-a-professional-mathematician/88249#88249), and one with more details on government work [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116309/the-non-traveling-mathematician-problem/116324#116324).

Comment: By the way, my masters advisor Danny Krizanc published some papers in computer science journals on DNA sequencing. Reading those would help you figure out how to best market yourself to the audience at these places I mentioned, e.g. how to present your expertise and how it would help solve their problems

Answer (score 2):

Companies hiring machine learning PhDs in USA:

1). Wall street hedge funds

2). Amazon

3). Twitter

4). Linkedin

5). IBM research labs.

6). Mitsubishi Electric Research Labs

7). United Technologies Research center